# Cómo referenciar un elemento en específico con pseudoclases dentro de un grupo en css

Tags: html, css

la mayoría de ejemplos de este palo que me he encontrado se hacen con las etiquetas 'id' o 'class'. Hasta ahora, no había necesitado otras, pero en esta ocasión me veo forzado a no utilizar ninguna y toda la ayuda que he podido encontrar es que simplemente utilice la pseudo clase 'nth-child' y sus variantes para poder referenciar a un elemento del html dentro del css que tengo que hacer. Como pone en el título de la pregunta, necesito seleccionar varios elementos en específico dentro de un mismo grupo y darle a cada uno unas propiedades diferentes. Por aquí voy dejando el código del html y del css que estoy haciendo en cuestión. También os dejo una imagen para que me podáis guiar mejor en cómo quiero que me quede al final la página. Muchas gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Baraja Española</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="baraja.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <h1>Las sotas de la baraja española</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
          <img src="sotaBastos.jpg" alt="sota de bastos" />
          <img src="sotaCopas.jpg" alt="sota de copas" />
          <img src="sotaEspadas.png" alt="sota de espadas" />
          <img src="sotaOros.jpg" alt="sota de oros" />
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
este es el css
*
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
}

body
{
  background-color: #013220;
  position: relative;
}

h1
{
  font: Arial;
  background-color: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 4.7em;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-right-color: black;
  border-left-color: black;
  position: static;
  height: max-content;
  width: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

/*main
{
  padding: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: middle;
  align-content: center;
  z-index: -1;
}
*/

[href="sotaBastos.jpg"]
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: -2;
}

[img="sotaCopas.jpg"]
{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  right: 150px;
  left: 10px;
}


[img="sotaOros.jpg"]
{
position: absolute;

}
```

[image: Lo importante del ejercicio son las cartas]

Comment: Olvidaste colocar el css

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Quieres que la varaja activa se muetre sobre todas las demas?. o ¿Quiere un CSS diferente para cada varaja?: Si es la primera puedes usar pseudo clases para ver el estado: [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), pero si es la segunda puedes usar el atributo `style` de cada imagen: `<img src="...." alt="..." style="/*Aqui va todo el estylo que le quieras poner*/"/>

Comment: Usando `pseudo-clases` puedes cambiar cada elemento segun su estado aunque hagas esto:`<style> img:hover{border:3px solid orange;}</style>` . Aunque tengas tres imagenes solo la que tu toques será la que tendrá un borde anaranjado. Pero si quieres puedes definir otro estylo cuando la persona deja la imagen.